# java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests (FAULTY COOKIE)

Tags: java, android, http, cookies, okhttp

i'm having this **Too many follow-up** problem, when i'm trying to make an **okhttp3 Request**, i found some similar problem's in stackoverflow & GitHub and most of them was pointing to Authentication errors. but in my case it's different

here's what i'm doing :

`Login into a website --> obtain cookie --> make okhttp3 request`

when i'm doing the above from a **desktop** it's working fine but i'm getting error on doing the same from my **android device**

i tried manually changing the userAgent of my webView, didn't worked.

then i tried to make the same call(From my android device) by using the **Cookie** which was obtained by 
**Desktop** and it worked, so i have this conclusion that **Android's Cookie** is causing the problem

So how can i solve this problem?

here's my code:

```
////LOGIN Completed///
final RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("key1","value1")
        .addFormDataPart("key2","value2")
        .build();

   final Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .addHeader("Cookie",""+mCookie)
         .url("example.com/request.php")
         .method("POST", RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]))
         .post(requestBody)
         .build();


 final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?